# Number of ways to color this graph.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, permutations

[image]

> Given the graph, what is number of ways to color the graph with $4$ colors such that no two adjacent vertices have same color.

According to me, the inner complete graph can be colored in $4*3*2*1$ ways =$24$ ways.

Now going to outer vertices, color for vertex $A$ can be chosen in $3$ ways, color for vertex $B$ in $2$,  color for $C$ in $2$ ways and color for last vertex in $1$ way. So number of ways is $3*2*2*1 = 12$ ways.

So total number of ways is $24*12 = 288$.

But this answer is wrong. I want to know where did I make a mistake. Can someone help me ?

Comment: If A and C have the same color, there are two possibilities for D, not just one.

Comment: And if $A, C$ and $G$ are all the same colour, then you even have $3$ choices for $D$.

Comment: So how to solve this ? There are many edge cases it seems when solving the outer part.

Comment: @Zephyr What do you consider "many" cases? I just counted them by hand. It took a few minutes. With the four inner colors fixed, I count $29$ ways to color the outer part, making a total of $24\times29=696.$ What's the answer supposed to be?

Comment: The answer is given as 625 .

Comment: @Zephyr $625$??? How can the answer not be divisible by $24$? There are $4!=24$ ways to color the four inner vertices, and each of those colorings can be extended in the same number of ways, since they only differ by a permutation of the colors.

Comment: What book is that from?

Comment: @bof yes I think book is wrong maybe some misprint. Thats why I posted the question here.

Comment: What book is it?

Comment: The book's answer $625$ could be a misprint for $624 = 26\times24$ which at least looks plausible but is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Your mistake is: When coloring $B$ you don't necessarily have $2$ ways. If you have chosen $A\mapsto f$ then you still have three ways for $B$. Similarly at later stages.

We may assume $E\mapsto e$, $F\mapsto f$, $G\mapsto g$, $H\mapsto h$. The vertices $A$ and $C$ can then be colored independently in $3$ ways each. Thereby four different types emerge, each of which leads to a characteristic number of possible continuations. The types are:

Type $1$: Both $A$ and $C$ are colored $e$ or $h$. There is $1$ coloring of this type: $A\mapsto h$, $C\mapsto e$. This enforces $B\mapsto g$, $D\mapsto f$. Makes $1$ in total.

Type $2$: One of $A$ and $C$ is colored $e$ or $h$, and the other $f$ or $g$. There are $4$ colorings of this type. Assume $A\mapsto h$, $C\mapsto f$. This allows of $B\mapsto\{e,g\}$ and enforces $D\mapsto e$. Makes $8$ in total.

Type $3$: $A$ and $C$ are differently colored $f$ or $g$. There are $2$ colorings of this type. This allows of $B\mapsto\{e,h\}$, $D\mapsto\{e,h\}$. Makes $8$ in total.

Type $4$: $A$ and $C$ are equally colored $f$ or $g$. There are $2$ colorings of this type. Assume $A\mapsto f$, $C\mapsto f$. This allows of $B\mapsto\{e,g,h\}$, $D\mapsto\{e,h\}$. Makes $12$ in total.

It follows that there are $29$ colorings of the eight vertices, up to a permutation of the colors. The grand total then is $29\cdot24=696$.

Comment: What about A colored as G?

Comment: This is counted under types $3$ and $4$.

Answer (score 1):

We are given four colors; call them e, f, g, h.

There are 4! = 24 ways to color the four inner vertices E, F, G, H; let's assume they are colored e, f, g, h in that order. I claim there are exactly 29 ways to extend this coloring to the whole graph. It's too late and I'm too tired to write a proof of that, so I will just show that there are at least 29 by exhibiting 29 colorings which you can check.

The outer vertices A, B, C, D (in that order) can be colored in the following ways:

1. h, g, e, f
2. h, g, f, e
3. f, g, e, h
4. g, h, e, f
5. h, e, g, f
6. h, e, f, e
7. h, e, g, e
8. f, g, f, e
9. f, g, f, h
10. f, h, e, h
11. g, h, e, h
12. g, e, g, f
13. g, h, g, f
14. f, e, f, e
15. f, e, f, h
16. f, e, g, e
17. f, e, g, h
18. f, h, f, e
19. f, h, f, h
20. f, h, g, e
21. f, h, g, h
22. g, e, f, e
23. g, e, f, h
24. g, e, g, e
25. g, e, g, h
26. g, h, f, e
27. g, h, f, h
28. g, h, g, e
29. g, h, g, h

I hope I typed that right. It was confusing of your book's author to label the outer vertices in cyclic order *but not the inner vertices*.

OK, there are 29 colorings. By permuting the 4 colors you get
$24\times29=696$ different colorings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This looks time consuming as we fix one outer vertex with a color and check all possible combinations. Is there any less time consuming way ?